# Spring read static file

Tags: spring, file, amazon-web-services, resources

I have a Spring web service that I am trying to integrate with Amazon CloudFront. To make a `signed url`, the CloudFront API expects a `java.io.File` object that contains the private key. The file is in the `.pem` format, and the API looks like follows:

```
String signedUrl = CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy(
                Protocol.https, 
                distributionDomainName, 
                cloudFrontPrivateKeyFile, // KEY FILE
                "/images/img.jpg", 
                cloudFrontKeyPairId, 
                expirationDate);
```

How would i load a file into memory in Spring? All the examples I found are loading a file from resources, like this:

```
final Resource fileResource = 
                resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:config/pk-mykey.pem");
cloudFrontPrivateKeyFile = fileResource.getFile()
```

However, this code throws the exception:

```
class path resource [config/pk-mykey.pem] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system:
```

Comment: It seems you are loading the file by using ClassPathResource; in this case your pem file should be under the classpath. If not possibile you should use another kind of Resource

Comment: @AngeloImmediata How do I add it under the classpath? The src/main/resources should be in the classpath, no? A code example would be great.